# How can I insulate exterior stuccoed walls from the interior side?

Tags: insulation, vapor-barrier, renovation, stucco

I am renovating two rooms of an old house and have removed the interior lathe/plaster with the intent to replace it with drywall. The walls were not insulated. My plan is to insulate these walls from the inside and protect the external stucco which appears be in good condition.

My thoughts are:

- Install XPS wall board first with a 3/4" air gap between the wall board and the exterior stucco lathes. This should provide sufficient circulation behind the stucco to keep it dry.
- The 1" wallboard will be followed by 3 1/2" rockwool batts. This will require building up the studs to the inside 1 3/4" to receive rockwool batts.
- Over this the drywall will be installed.

The only remaining question is what type, if any, vapor barrier would be needed between the drywall and the rockwool?

Is this a sound approach?

Comment: I'm not a stucco expert, but do you _really_ need a full 3/4" air gap? I know that there are loose woven plastic mats that are designed to go under real wood cedar shingles to provide air flow to allow them to dry. Maybe you could cut that into stud-bay wide strips and install it as the outer most layer of your new system. This would A) be easier to maintain the space, B) provide for air flow, and C) minimize the amount of non-insulated space.

Comment: FreeMan, I like your edits, it sounds much better. Thanks.

Comment: Good, clear communication is difficult. I've been married 33 years and we still misunderstand each other all the time...